# Модификация smSlider

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте, суть такова:
Нужно модифицировать скрипт слайдера, чтобы задержка нулевого слайда и задержка остальных слайдов были разными опциями. Например выставить задержку первого слайда в 5 секунд, а всех остальных 15 секунд.

[Ссылка на скрипт](https://github.com/sashamochalin/smSlider/archive/master.zip) / [Страница скрипта](http://sashamochalin.github.io/smSlider/index.html)

Пожалуйста, поясните как справится с данной задачей. Заранее огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Практически ничего в плагине не исправлял, хотя одолевает пичалька в некоторых моментах. Добавил только костыль (*по другому не назовешь*), для вашей задачи. Для начала - [вот рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/T7Epz/). Теперь поясню.

- строка 18 (*в примере*) - добавляем: **diffDelay : false**;
- строка 174, 177, 179 - изменяем **setInterval** и **clearIterval** на **setTimeout** и **clearTimeout** соответственно и изменяем **options.delay** на **options.diffDelay ? options.diffDelay[cIndex] : options.delay;**
- строка 171 - после **slideMove(cIndex, 'next');** добавляем, как в примере: **timeOut = setTimeout(autoPlay, (options.diffDelay ? options.diffDelay[cIndex] : options.delay));**

В опциях подключения плагина, прописываем параметр **diffDelay** с массивом значений задержек для кажгодо слайда отдельно. Кол-во значение должно быть равным кол-ву слайдов!!! В примере, установил для первого слайда задержку 3000, для второго 1000 и для третьего - 8000. И обратите внимание, что если вы задаете параметр **diffDelay**, то **delay** будет просто игнорироваться.

---

**UPD** P.S. Хотя я так подумал, что не обязательно делать количество значений равным количеству слайдов. Изменяем везде (три кусочка кода):

```
options.diffDelay ? options.diffDelay[cIndex] : options.delay
// на следующее
options.diffDelay[cIndex] ? options.diffDelay[cIndex] : options.delay
```

Теперь, если надо задать задержку только для первого слайда пишем так:

```
$(your_elem_selector).smSlider({
    autoPlay   : true,
    duration       : 500,
    diffDelay : [1000]
});
// Только для второго слайда
$(your_elem_selector).smSlider({
    autoPlay   : true,
    duration       : 500,
    diffDelay : [null, 1000]
});
// Для второго и четвертого слайда
$(your_elem_selector).smSlider({
    autoPlay   : true,
    duration       : 500,
    diffDelay : [null, 1000, null, 4000]
});
// И так далее...
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно немного проще — не лезть в код самого `smSlider()`.
У него есть опции-функции с помощью которых можно управлять настройками слайдера.
Если взять `.animationComplete`, это функция, которая знает параметр `toIndex` — номер слайда.
Можно завязываться на этот параметр.

Все настройки слайдера доступны в этой функции через `this`, только в случае изменения опции `delay`, надо сбрасывать внутренний `timeOut` слайдера. Его можно сбросить наведением курсора на слайдер.

То есть, пишем мини-функцию `timerClear()`

```
var $smSlider = $('#sm_slider');

var timerClear = function(){
    $smSlider.mouseover(); // навели курсор
    $smSlider.mouseout();    // убрали курсор
};
```

И используем ее в слайдере, как-нибудь так:

```
$smSlider.smSlider({
    autoPlay   : true,
    delay      : 15000,
    animationComplete : function(toIndex) {
         switch(toIndex) {
           case 0: 
              timerClear();
              this.delay = 1000; // время задержки перед вторым слайдом одна секунда
              break
           case 1:
              timerClear();
              this.delay = 2000; // время задержки две секунды
              break
           default:
              timerClear();
              // для всех остальных слайдов ставим 15 секунд
              this.delay = 15000;
            }
        }
    });
```